# Is there a medical condition that prevents running laps but allows all other exercise?

Tags: health

There is an 11 year old kid on the football team that I coach that has a slip from his doctor that states that he is unable to run laps.  He is permitted to do everything else, and can even run as many sprints as we want.  I am very uncomfortable with these instructions.  I can run the kid 6 x 100 yard sprints, but I can't have him run a 400 yard lap?  What happens to me when he drops on the 5th 100 yard sprint?  My philosophy as a coach has always been your are physically able to do 100% or you don't participate.  I understand that if a kid has a sprained wrist he can run but he can't do push-ups.  However, I want him released 100%.  I'm not going to have him reinjure something and me be held responsible.  The doctor needs to release him to do everything at practice.  Has anybody heard of such a medical condition?

Comment: Perhaps you could talk to the parent and find out what the condition is.

Comment: Sounds like the same condition as [Derek Zoolander](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0196229/) - he can't turn left.

Comment: great question !

Comment: Sounds like a dupe to me, but then I'm not a doctor.

Comment: I know of no condition, but I am aware of the different types of _conditioning_ involved.  It would be odd to get the doctor in on this though.  See: http://startingstrength.com/articles/death_by_prowler_reynolds.pdf

Answer (score 3):

You can generate hip problems from running in circles excessively.  Many runners have leg-length issues, and many times it is the left leg that is 1/4" - 1/2" shorter than the right.  If you constantly turn/pivot one the left this happens.  This is usually a result of the pelvis becoming rotated over time, though knee cartilage can compress as well.  I've been running on a track since I was 14 and my legs are different lengths as a result, though most of my issues are from a rotated pelvis - which according to my chiropractor is not rare among runners.

I've seen many coaches instruct runners to run some workouts in the opposite direction on a track to prevent injury.  Stress fractures in the lower leg are possible as well from constant turns in one direction.

If the kid already has a bad leg length issues or hip rotation issues this could be a cause.  However this is speculation...

Comment: Sounds like pretty good speculation to me. I did a search, and [shin splints](http://www.best-running-tips.com/shin-splints.html) are also caused by "too much running in circles, which puts too much stress on the inner leg".

Comment: Quite a plausible answer. Of course it would have been much more useful for the doctor to explain that in the note.